# Souvenir shops at Heydar Aliyev (Baku) airport?

Tags: airports, azerbaijan, souvenirs, gyd, baku

I have an upcoming trip, later this month, that includes a short (1-1/2 hour) stopover in Heydar Aliyev (Baku) airport. Having never been to Azerbaijan before, I'd like to be able to pick up some kind of local souvenirs there for my family (even if just the typical airport-shop knickknacks with the name of the country on them).

Are there such shops there that are accessible to transfer passengers (without going through passport control, which would require a visa, which I don't have)?

Comment: I was able to determine that [there are duty-free and other shops in the transit area](http://www.azal.az/images/about/airport_baku_01_en.jpg), but aside from the duty-free I was not able to determine what specific shops there are. This airport's web site is very short on information...

Comment: @MichaelHampton wow, I went to the website too, surprisingly unhelpful compared to others which have pages on the shopping alone!

Comment: "Unlike most other international airports, there are shops not only in the departures but also in the arrivals area..  Hmm, let's see, recent airports I've been to - Melbourne, yes, Sydney, yes, Christchurch, Tokyo, Singapore...yes they all have shops in arrival.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The airport had a huge renovation in 2013, so things are a bit hectic there.

I believe you're flying with AZAL (Azerbaijan Airlines), so you should be in the new fancy terminal. I was there this summer, and there was a shop after passport control (and hence in the transit area, in front of the gates) where you could buy souvenirs.

Comment: Thanks, and +1. But when you say "after passport control (and hence in the transit area)," aren't those contradictory? Or do you mean "after" relative to when you're coming into the terminal?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking only from a point of view of someone who begins journey in Baku. I meant the passport control when you're leaving the country and getting on the plane. For transfers, you will be directly at the transit area, since there's no passport control.

Comment: Having completed my trip, and for the benefit of future travelers who may have this question, the souvenir shop Elchin mentioned is near Gate 12.